# beginTransaction in symfomy2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm learning and I have more doubts about Doctrine and Symfony

What is the best practice for persist?
Now i'm using this:

```
try {
        $em = $this->getEm();
        $em->beginTransaction();
        $product = new \Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product();
        $product->setName('foo');
        $product->setPrice('19.99');
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();
        $em->commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $em->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
```

But In symfony documentation, there isn't beginTransaction.
And What is the different between  `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` `$em = $this->getDoctrine()`? When to use one or the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're doing there, you wouldn't need to use `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` since `flush()` would basically take care of that.

`persist()` is used for inserting new entities into your database, and `flush()` actually performs the databse operation.  If you already have the entity fetched and then modify it, you don't need `persist()` since Doctrine is already managing it.

You would use `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` when you are in a Symfony controller to get the entity manager.

When you call `$this->getDoctrine()` it returns the Doctrine Registry service (equivalent to `$this->container->get('doctrine');`) which references all of your Doctrine connections and entity managers.

Further documentation:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

The best way to learn is to read the docs and experiment. Symfony documentation provides excellent examples and explanations.

Comment: thnaks, little bit clear. When I have to use beginTransaction? in doctrine link, it used in an example like mine.

Comment: Right, the Doctrine link had that because I linked you to the transactions section. It depends on your use case really.  The simplest reason to need it would be if you're performing multiple database operations, and if one fails you want all of the other operations to fail as well and not rollback.  Or if you think there's a good chance the query will cause an Exception and you want to catch and handle it.